# Determine if a function of 2 variables is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

I am given a function:
$$ f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
        8 & (x,y)=(2,0) \\
        4x+y+\frac{xy-2y}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+y^2+4}} & (x,y)\neq(2,0)
    \end{cases}
$$

I have to determine if this function is differentiable. I am not sure how to approach this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: My guess is that under the square root you should have $x^2\color{red}{-}4x+y^2+4$.